# Does snowflake charge for the data ingestion?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Does Snowflake charge for data ingestion ? and if so is there specifics of the cost depend on the type of data ingestion and the associated data transfer and storage resources used. I understand that Snowflake's pricing model is based on a combination of factors including compute usage, storage usage, and data transfer ( only sending out from snowflake ) Please confirm ?

Answer (score 2):

When you ingest data to Snowflake you use a Virtual Warehouse, therefore it goes towards the compute usage. You can choose the size of the warehouse to balance the price and the ingestion performance.

Once ingested it goes toward the storage.

Snowflake does not charge for data ingress, but consider the data egress from where you bringing the data from.

Comment: You can ingest data without using a warehouse using Snowpipe. It too uses credits, but in some cases may be more credit efficient than using a warehouse, especially for small data volumes with low latency requirements to arrive in destination tables.

Comment: Thanks, it is a valid addition. Still the compute credits, but different considerations should be applied to estimate and monitor the usage of the credits.